# Forecast data with seasonality with machine learning

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, seasonality

I have a basic knowledge on econometric techniques for forecasting, and I was reading about [Forecasting with decomposition](https://otexts.com/fpp3/forecasting-decomposition.html).

My data seems to show high seasonality as can be seen in the following picture:

[image]

If my understanding is correct, after decomposing the time series in its components with (e.g.) [`STL`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/stl), I can forecast the seasonally adjusted component and then sum the `season_year` to the results to obtain predictions in the original scale. Is this correct?

I am using Machine Learning (Random Forest precisely) to perform the forecasting, and my questions are:

1. Does decomposing the time series like I am doing make sense when using ML?
2. Since I am using other covariates to forecast, do I need to decompose them as well and use their seasonally adjusted values instead of the original ones?

In the past I used to add dummy variables like `quarter(date)` to my model to account for the seasonal effect, but maybe this is better.

Comment: Your data doesn't look seasonal at all. What makes you think it is?

Comment: Note that the "seasonal" component of an STL decomposition will fit a seasonally-looking component *regardless of the data*, and that in your case this component is on a scale that is about 10 times smaller than the original data. As Rob writes, your original series is absolutely nonseasonal. Don't just look at the "seasonal" STL component!

Comment: Thanks for these info. Indeed, I was probably misled by the 3rd plot without taking into account its scale.